# Splitting input values in angular 2 form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

Hi am using angular 2 forms,

I have an inout field to key in users GSTIN value.
GSTIN format is XX-XXXXXXXXXX-X-X-X alphanumeric. What i need achieve is once the user keyin the values, I need to add a hyphen in to the keyed in value as per the format mentioned above.

HTML:

```
<custom-input [autocomplete]="false" [type]="'text'" [autocapitalize]="true" (change)="onGstinValChange($event)" (focusout)="onChangeGSTIN($event)"
                        [maxlength]="15" [formControl]="enterpriseDetailForm.controls['GSTIN']"
                        (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)" 
                        [ngModel]="iban_no"></custom-input>
```

TS:

```
mychange(val) {
    if (val) {
        const self = this;
        let gstin = val.split('-').join('');
        if (gstin.length > 0) {
            gstin = gstin.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join('-');
        }
        console.log(gstin);
        this.dataGstin = gstin;
    }
}
```

With this function i can split every 2 values. Can someone help me on how i can achieve my format mentioned above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont mix Reactive form approach with the Template drive form approach , just use one

so if you go with reactive form apporch then code will be

```
<custom-input [autocomplete]="false" [type]="'text'" [autocapitalize]="true" (change)="onGstinValChange($event)" (focusout)="onChangeGSTIN($event)"
                        [maxlength]="15" [formControl]="GSTIN"
                        ></custom-input>
```

there is no need of `(ngModelChange)="mychange($event)" [ngModel]="iban_no"` as its template driven attributes

```
onGstinValChange($event){
 let inputtext =  $event.Traget.value;
 ///do code for adding - as per formate
 enterpriseDetailForm.get('GSTIN').setValue(inputtext);
}
```

---

or just use reactive monitor change in value

```
  ngOnInit() {   
    this.enterpriseDetailForm.get('GSTIN').valueChanges.subscribe(val =>     
     {
        let gstin = val.split('-').join('');
        if (gstin.length > 0) {
           gstin = gstin.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join('-');
         }
       enterpriseDetailForm.get('GSTIN').setValue(gstin );
     }
      , {emitEvent: false}));
 }
```

---

html will be

```
<custom-input [autocomplete]="false" [type]="'text'" [autocapitalize]="true" 
               (focusout)="onChangeGSTIN($event)"
                        [maxlength]="15" [formControl]="GSTIN"
                        ></custom-input>
```

Comment: @chewi - that need so it will not raise change event for contorl